# React native Linking.getInitialUrl on Android called always

Tags: android, react-native, deep-linking, react-native-navigation

I've a React-Native app with the following code (here App.js, the app entry point) that manages deep link on Android.

```
Linking.getInitialURL().then((deepLinkUrl) => {
  if (deepLinkUrl) {
    manageDeepLink(deepLinkUrl);
  } else {
    Navigation.startSingleScreenApp('rootScreen');
  }
});
```

The problem here is that getInitialURL is called every time I launch my app, from both deep link or normally, and everytime it contains *deepLinkUrl* parameter empty.
I've registered in AndroidManifest my intent as follows:

```
<application
    android:name=".MainApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <!-- deeplink -->
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="myapp" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

**UPDATE**
I'm using react-native navigation to register screens, if this can e useful.

Comment: I'm having this problem as well, have you found any solution?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 2):

It seems it doesn't work if you register listener too soon in the app lifecycle (ex. directly in some .js file, so it's executed when app is loaded).

If you move it into `componentDidMount()` on the root component everything works fine.

```
    componentDidMount() {
        Linking.addEventListener('url', event => {
            console.warn('URL', event.url)
        })

        Linking.getInitialURL().then(url => {
            console.warn('INITIAL', url)
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you added `android:launchMode="singleTask"` to AndroidManifest.xml. Please modify it to `android:launchMode="singleTop"`, then your problem will be gone.